# Adding records from two SQL Server tables that are unique on one column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables in a SQL Server database, one containing letters that are posted and one of documents that are sent electronically.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentTransmission]
(
    [PatientNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Filename] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [TransmittedDateTime] [datetime2](3) NULL,
    [GPCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PracticeCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MessageSource] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [DateTimeAdded] [datetime2](3) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The other table is called `DocumentPrint`

I need to be able to select records from `DocumentTransmission` and only those from `DocumentPrint` where the `Filename` does **NOT** appear in `DocumentTransmission` - and I can't seem to figure out how to do this quickly - the routine I have would make a DBA cry as it is so slow - how would you recommend this is done.

Comment: sound like a left join to me

Comment: [see here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sPPmxWgcl_I/UmrMDwV5EhI/AAAAAAAAAHU/fFApXiKcHwg/s1600/sqljoins.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean you want to do something like this `SELECT * FROM DocumentTransmission UNION SELECT * FROM DocumentPrint WHERE Filename NOT IN (SELECT FileName FROM DocumentTransmission)`?  If so it will be hard to make it fast since you are comparing two very long `VARCHAR` columns.

Comment: Just want to know, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *adding records* in SQL.  However, you can *merge* two (or more) `SELECT` results together with an `UNION`.  Something like :

```
SELECT * FROM DocumentTransmission UNION SELECT * FROM DocumentPrint
```

Since you also want to exclude rows from the second query you have to add a condition :

```
SELECT * FROM DocumentTransmission UNION SELECT * FROM DocumentPrint WHERE Filename NOT IN (SELECT FileName FROM DocumentTransmission)
```

But don't expect this query to be very fast : you are comparing two very long `VARCHAR` columns and this is going to be slow if you have many rows in your table.